# How can I remove different English layouts in windows 10, when they are not shown in control panel?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-layout, layout

[image]

In the picture above you can see that in control panel I have 2 languages, but at the same time in the right bottom corner it is showing 4.

I don't want English international and English UK to be there, how can I remove them?

Answer (score 0):

Control Panel -> Clock, Language, and Region -> Language ->click English(United States) **Options**-> Under **Input method** part -> remove English international and English UK

Comment: Nope, there was no such thing, I had to reinstall windows to remove those...